# issue with editing model using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations

I have three models - a donar, a recipient and a gift,

The donor model - has_one :recipient, belongs_to :gift, accepts_nested_attributes_for, :recipient, accepts_nested_attributes_for :gift

The recipient model - belongs_to :donor

And the gift model -  has_many :donors

When a user is on the show page  - /donors/1 - I'd like to be able to edit the recipient and add a gift. They are editing all three models from one form.

My show action in the controller is providing a form to add a reciient to the donar on that form through @recipient = @donor.build_recipient - I set up the form in the view. This works!

however I'm trying to allow the user to attach a preexisting gift to a user through a select box using -

```
<%= select(:gift, :gift_id, Gift.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },  {:prompt => 'Select gift'}) %>
```

This is displaying a select box with all of the gifts listed from the table.

When I submit the form I can edit the donor's details, add a recipient, but the gift model (or the donor's relationship with a gift) is not updating at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like that:

```
<% form_for @donor do |f| %>

  ...

  <% f.select :gift_id, Gift.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

In that case there's no need for `accepts_nested_attributes_for :gift` as you are selecting gift from a list of available ones instead of creating it in the donor form.